# How to understand PlaySound function API document and implement it in MASM?

Tags: assembly, winapi, x86, masm, masm32

I know that putting 20001h in PlaySound function as the last parameter can make the music play synchronously. But why is 20001h? I also wanted the music played in the background "repeatedly" but I couldn't understand the API document since it does not mention 20001h stands for SND_SYNC nor show what stands for SND_LOOP.
Need some enlightenment, big thank!

This is my code:

```
includelib Winmm.lib
PlaySound PROTO,
        pszSound:PTR BYTE, 
        hmod:DWORD, 
        fdwSound:DWORD

file BYTE "test.wav",0
SND_SYNC DWORD 0

main proc
    mov SND_SYNC, 20001H 
    INVOKE PlaySound, OFFSET file, NULL, SND_SYNC

.......
```

Comment: The documentation is for the C API.  If you need the numerical constants for hand-written asm, you need to look in the `.h` headers (or write a C program that prints their values, and compile+run it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that putting 20001h in PlaySound function as the last parameter can make the music play synchronously.

That is incorrect. It plays the file **asynchronously**.

The last parameter is a bitmask, it can hold multiple flags OR'ed together. `SND_SYNC` is defined as `00000h` (the absence of any other flags), whereas `20001h` is a combination of `SND_ASYNC` (`00001h`) OR'ed with `SND_FILENAME` (`20000h`).

`SND_LOOP` (`00008h`) can only be used in combination with `SND_ASYNC`.

So, to accomplish what you want:

> I also wanted the music played in the background "repeatedly"

You need to combine the `SND_FILENAME`, `SND_ASYNC`, and `SND_LOOP` flags. That numeric value is `20009h`.

Here are all of the flags you can use with `PlaySound()`. Their meanings are explained in [`PlaySound`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)) <sup>1</sup>:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| SND_SYNC | 0x00000000 |
| SND_ASYNC | 0x00000001 |
| SND_NODEFAULT | 0x00000002 |
| SND_MEMORY | 0x00000004 |
| SND_LOOP | 0x00000008 |
| SND_NOSTOP | 0x00000010 |
| SND_PURGE | 0x00000040 |
| SND_APPLICATION | 0x00000080 |
| SND_NOWAIT | 0x00002000 |
| SND_ALIAS | 0x00010000 |
| SND_ALIAS_ID | 0x00110000 |
| SND_FILENAME | 0x00020000 |
| SND_RESOURCE | 0x00040000 |
| SND_SENTRY | 0x00080000 |
| SND_RING | 0x00100000 |
| SND_SYSTEM | 0x00200000 |

<sup>1</sup> Note: `SND_RING` is undocumented, but you can see that `SND_ALIAS_ID` is a combination of `SND_RING` OR'ed with `SND_ALIAS`.

Comment: Fantastic! thank you for the detailed instruction. But is there a way to play two sounds at the same time? the first sound is interrupted when the second one plays and not continued after the second one is finished. The document seems not to mention this matter.

Comment: @Kevin "*is there a way to play two sounds at the same time?*" - not with `PlaySound()`, no. You will have to use more advanced playback APIs (waveOut, DirectSound, XAudio, etc) which can mix multiple sounds while playing.

Comment: Alright Remy, Thank you!!